# Converting String[] to Expando for binding DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, dynamic, wpf-controls, binding

I am working on a system that parses files and imports them into a WPF DataGrid. The files are split into a collection string[] and passed back to me to display in the UI.

What is the easiest way to convert this collection of string[] into something that can be bound to a WPF (.NET4) DataGrid?

Aside: I'd like to use Expando .....

Comment: Are the string[] strings the paths to the files...or?

Comment: its easy to bind to string[], whats the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately dynamic objects like `Expando` do not work yet with WPF4 in my testing.  However, there are other tried and true methods that are available.

For a collection of `String[]`, you can use a `DataTable` to give you dynamic columns:

```
var rawData = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "R1F1", "R1F2", },
    new string[] { "R2F1", "R2F2", },
};
var fieldNames = Enumerable.Range(1, rawData[0].Length).Select(field => "Field" + field);
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.AddRange(fieldNames.Select(fieldName => new DataColumn(fieldName)).ToArray());
foreach (var record in rawData)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < record.Length; i++)
    {
        row[i] = record[i];
    }
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
DataContext = table;
```

together with XAML like this:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: +1 for pointing out that WPF DataGrid won't auto-generate columns based on the fields of Expando or Dynamic objects. I suppose they're not proerties, after all. Anyway, it saved me from having to give it a try.

Comment: I should clarify that dynamic properties do work in in WPF4 in binding expressions but that they are not discoverable via ICustomTypeDescriptor so DataGrid cannot auto-create the columns.  But if you define the columns yourself, even the DataGrid can show dynamic properties.  It just kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Thanks Rick. What I needed yesterday was the ability for DataGrid to auto-generate columns for the anonymously typed objects created by a LINQ Join (to BindingList). I ended up writing a CodeDom based anonymous type promoter that reflects on the anonymous type at runtime to create a full type with backing field, public property accessors, and constructor accepting the anonymous object. If anyone wants this code, contact me.